# Download file from Mongodb using griddfs in golang

Tags: mongodb, file, go, gridfs

I have already uploaded my files using gridfs in go lang. But having problems in downloading it...I dont know how to read the file in the MongoDB and show it in browser and once the user clicks it i want to download it to the users computer Please help me..Thanks

Comment: What did you try? Are you talking about Mongodb instead of mangoDB?

Comment: I am not getting your question? Is it you can't read file from mongodb or you can't send the file to the front-end?

Comment: sorry for the confusion.I can able to download the file from mangodb without the browser.I dont know how to send to the browser and download it from there if user clicks it, in golang.I m using Beegoapi as the framework for developing the golang and use json to pass values to the front end.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to do it.
All we have do is read from the GridFS and write it in the response writer and set the content disposition to attachment or inline and set the content type and length.
Thanks for the effort of others...